# Pattern matching on records in F#

Tags: f#, idioms

Is there a more idiomatic way how to do pattern matching on records? My code just doesn't seem right.

```
type Period = AM | PM

type TimeOfDay = {hours : int; minutes : int; p : Period}

let before (tod1 : TimeOfDay, tod2 : TimeOfDay) =
   match tod1, tod2 with
   | {hours = h1; minutes = m1; p = AM}, {hours = h2; minutes = m2; p = AM} -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | {hours = h1; minutes = m1; p = PM}, {hours = h2; minutes = m2; p = PM} -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | {hours = _; minutes = _; p = AM}, {hours = _; minutes = _; p = PM} -> true
   | {hours = _; minutes = _; p = PM}, {hours = _; minutes = _; p = AM} -> false
```

Comment: If you moved `Period` to be the first field in `TimeOfDay`, then  `TimeOfDay` values would naturally sort in the order you expect, so you can just use `tod1 < tod2`. This works because `AM` comes before `PM` in your definition of `Period`. Doesn't help with your question though.

Comment: And if for some reason you can't reorder the record fields (eg if they come from an external library), you can still do `(tod1.p, tod1.hours, tod1.minutes) < (tod2.p, tod2.hours, tod2.minutes)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can switch to 24h time: `let adjust = function | {hours=h; minutes=m; p=PM} -> {hours=h+12; minutes=m; p=AM} | x -> x` and then compare the results of application of this function to both records: `let before (tod1, tod2) = adjust tod1 < adjust tod2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a slight improvement as you don't need to show unneeded patterns to produce the following

```
let before (tod1 : TimeOfDay, tod2 : TimeOfDay) =
   match tod1, tod2 with
   | {hours = h1; minutes = m1; p = AM}, {hours = h2; minutes = m2; p = AM} -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | {hours = h1; minutes = m1; p = PM}, {hours = h2; minutes = m2; p = PM} -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | { p = AM}, {p = PM} -> true
   | { p = PM}, {p = AM} -> false
```

Next, you could define an Active Pattern to deconstruct the type into a Tuple as follows

```
let (|TIME|) (t:TimeOfDay) = t.hours,t.minutes,t.p

let before (tod1 : TimeOfDay, tod2 : TimeOfDay) =
   match tod1, tod2 with
   | TIME(h1,m1,AM), TIME(h2,m2,PM) -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | TIME(h1,m1,PM), TIME(h2,m2,PM) -> (h1, m1) < (h2, m2)
   | { p = AM}, {p = PM} -> true
   | { p = PM}, {p = AM} -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the properties that you dont need on the match, use "guards" (when clauses) to check if both `p`properties are equals, and create a local function to simplify tuple comparasion.

```
let before (tod1: TimeOfDay, tod2: TimeOfDay) =
   let getTime tod = (tod.hours, tod.minutes)
   match tod1, tod2 with
   | { p = x }, { p = y } when x = y -> getTime tod1 < getTime tod2
   | { p = AM }, _ -> true
   | _ -> false
```

or to remove the last pattern just do

```
let before (tod1: TimeOfDay, tod2: TimeOfDay) =
   let getTime tod = (tod.hours, tod.minutes)
   match tod1, tod2 with
   | { p = x }, { p = y } when x = y -> getTime tod1 < getTime tod2
   | { p = x }, _ -> x = AM
```